Firebase Auth / Analytics - is it using the Phone number?
I got an issue for my app from Google review team claiming that my app stores the users phone number and I need to update my policy declaration.
The only things I can think of that could store these infos are - funnily enough - 2 Google services I use: Firebase Auth and Firebase Analytics.
I have no other code actually having to do something with this. However, in Firebase Auth, only OAuth (Google and Apple) is activated, no user/pw / sms etc. login functionality.
For now, I appealed and asked for more info, however, I would appreciate your insights, if you have any idea.
Btw, I checked the infos that I can retrieve from Firebase Auth, and the phonenumber-field is there on all records but always undefined.
Thanks!
